# get list of subscribed users for AWS appSync

Tags: ios, swift, aws-appsync

Is there currently anyway to get a list of subscribed users?

I want to create a chat room and let people know when users are entering or leaving the room which they do by subscription to the mutations containing that room ID.

Comment: I work on AWS AppSync. The feature you requested is not available at this time. I've added your use case to the AWS AppSync backlog.